# Pruned decision tree in r, ctree

Tags: r, controls, decision-tree, party, ctree

I'm developing a binary decision tree in R with the "party" package, ctree.
Further, I want to prune the tree with some controls (ctree_control) e.g., maxdepth, minsplit, and mtry. The model looks something like this:

```
tree <- ctree(Class ~ ., data = train, controls = ctree_control(mincriterion = 0.99,minsplit = 500))
```

How can I visualize the controls to choose the optimal criterion?

Comment: Just to understand the question better. Do you want to visualize if, for example, the constrain you imposed, say `minsplit=500`, was actually an active restriction?

Comment: This will probably depend on how exactly you do the selection of the parameters. Note that there are also packages like `caret`, for example, that offer automatic tuning for `ctree`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas Yes, I want to vizualize that e.g. minsplit=500 is the optimal constraint for the model